# share intent - how to open shared url in my app ONLY

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, share

Is this even possible?
I want to open a shared URL (that's shared using my app) with my app only. Instead of having a dialog with options like Chrome, Browser and my_app_name, I want to click on the link and for it to be opened automatically by my app.

I have a share intent as a plugin in cordova

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
context.startActivity(sendIntent);

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:host="<host>"> </data>
<data android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

In my intent I have tried to set the package (setPackage) and set the class (setClassName) but I end up with an exception, ActivityNotFoundException, Invalid action.

I've tried a bunch of things with no success.

Comment: "I want to open a shared URL (that's shared using my app) with my app only" -- then why are you using `ACTION_SEND` in the first place? The **point** of `ACTION_SEND` is to allow the user to share content from your app **via other apps**. If you don't want that, don't use `ACTION_SEND`. Simply trigger your own app logic directly instead.

Comment: Sorry I'm not an Android developer so what do you mean? What should I use. I want to have a share button in my app that shares a url to a page in my app. Then once the user has shared that link, the user should be able to click on that link and open that shared page using my app.

Comment: "What should I use" -- since you are using Cordova, you should be using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. "that shares a url to a page in my app" -- please explain what you mean by this. Do you mean that you are showing the URL to the user? "Then once the user has shared that link" -- please explain what you mean by this. Do you mean that the user should spray-paint the URL on the side of a building? "the user should be able to click on that link and open that shared page using my app" -- why not just open the page when the user clicks the button? What "sharing" is involved in that?

Comment: Let me simplify, lets say there's a hyper link that has the scheme and host I defined in my intent-filter. If a user clicks on this, right now I see a dialog pop up that offers three options to open this link with, my app, browser and chrome. What I want is for only my app to show as an option (so to eliminate Browser and Chrome). Or even better would be for the user to click on the link and for it to automatically open in my app without showing the dialog box first.

Comment: "lets say there's a hyper link" -- if the link is in your app, get rid of the link, and do something else *within your app* when the user interacts with it. If the link is in an arbitrary Web page, email, or other source outside your app, you cannot prevent other apps from offering to handle the same scheme.

Comment: The link will be in some other app like email or text, etc. Ok thanks, I guess there's nothing I can do then.

Comment: You are welcome to invent your own custom scheme (e.g., `marcia://`) and use that in the links and in the `<intent-filter>`. However, not everything will recognize `marcia://` strings as being clickable links, so it probably won't work in an email or text. It also is useless if the user does not have your app installed, whereas `http://` links could also resolve to a real Web page to lead users to download the app. OTOH, it is far less likely that anyone else has a `marcia://` app, and therefore more likely that where the links work, they will uniquely open your app, if it is installed.

Comment: I have tried doing my own scheme and like you said emails don't recognize it as a clickable link. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an intent that targets your class explicitly:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
//add extras here
```